# On solving the equation $\sin ^{2}\left ( z \right )= i\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

One obvious approach is to rewrite $\sin\left ( z \right )$ as $\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$ and then proceed applying an appropriate substitution. However that leads to a quartic complex equation, which gets a bit(actually a lot) messy. Is there another(maybe obscure) approach suitable for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
sin(z) = \pm \sqrt{i \pi} \\
e^{iz} - e^{-iz} = \pm 2i \sqrt{i \pi}
$$

Let $e^{iz} = x$, then $x^2 \pm 2i \sqrt{i \pi} x - 1 = 0$.

Hence:

$e^{iz} = x = \frac{\pm 2i \sqrt{i \pi} \pm \sqrt{-4i \pi +4}}{2} = \pm i \sqrt{i \pi} \pm  \sqrt{1-i \pi}$

Thus, $z = -i \log(\pm i \sqrt{i \pi} \pm  \sqrt{1-i \pi})$.

Or:

$$
z_1 = -i \log(i \sqrt{i \pi} +  \sqrt{1-i \pi}) \\
z_2 = -i \log(i \sqrt{i \pi} -  \sqrt{1-i \pi}) \\
z_3 = -i \log(-i \sqrt{i \pi} +  \sqrt{1-i \pi}) \\
z_4 = -i \log(-i \sqrt{i \pi} -  \sqrt{1-i \pi})
$$

As $\log(-1) = i (1 + 2k) \pi$, $z_3 = z_2 + i(1+2k) \pi$, and $z_4 = z_1 + i(1+2k) \pi$, for $k$ integer.

Comment: Actually $\sin(z) = \pm \sqrt{ \mathbf{i} \pi }$...

Comment: @johannesvalks Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can replace $\sin z = w$ and notice that $w$ solve the equaiton $w^2=i\pi.$

This means that $\sin z$ can either be $\sqrt\pi e^{i \frac\pi4}$ or $\sqrt\pi e^{\frac{5\pi}{4}}$.

Then, you are solving the easier equation of $\sin z = w$ for some known $w$...

Comment: I will try that. At first glance it seem like there will be four instead of two sets of solutions as shown in wolfram alpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+ccomplex+z%2C+%28sin%28z%29%29%5E2%3Di*pi

Comment: @Shemafied Which makes sense since there are two values of $w$ you can solve for.